# How to make certain sections/rows images full width on my Wordpress homepage?

Tags: php, wordpress, css, width

I'm working on a new startup and am using Wordpress and Woothemes for my initial MVP. I use the Hustle theme and everything looks gorgeous. I'm a bit pedantic though and want to display certain images in full width on the "home page" while the other sections stay at 99em width.

What's the best way to approach this? I'm not very good at PHP, but want to do it right. Is changing the CSS code the most efficient way to do this though and then how would I isolate just the one piece of section and make it full width?

Here is the CSS of the one section I want to make full width i.o.w it should override the block its in:

```
.home-section#intro-message {
  width: 
  margin-top: -6.854em;
  padding: 6.854em 0;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #e5e5e5;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

PHP FILE:

```
<?php
// File Security Check
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp' ) && ! empty( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) && basename( __FILE__ ) == basename( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) ) {
    die ( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page!' );
}
?><?php
/**
 * Index Template
 *
 * Here we setup all logic and XHTML that is required for the index template, used as both the homepage
 * and as a fallback template, if a more appropriate template file doesn't exist for a specific context.
 *
 * @package WooFramework
 * @subpackage Template
 */
    get_header();
    global $woo_options;

    $settings = array(
                'homepage_enable_intro_message' => 'true', 
                'homepage_enable_blog_posts' => 'true', 
                'homepage_enable_promotion' => 'true', 
                'homepage_enable_featured_products' => 'true',
                'homepage_enable_features' => 'true',
                'homepage_enable_testimonials' => 'true',
                'homepage_number_of_features' => 3, 
                'homepage_number_of_testimonials' => 3, 
                'homepage_features_area_title' => '', 
                'homepage_testimonials_area_title' => ''
                );

    $settings = woo_get_dynamic_values( $settings );

?>

    <div id="content" class="col-full">

        <?php woo_main_before(); ?>

        <section id="main" class="col-full fullwidth">      
        <?php if ( is_home() && ! dynamic_sidebar( 'homepage' ) ) {
            if ( 'true' == $settings['homepage_enable_intro_message'] ) {
                get_template_part( 'includes/intro-message' );
            }

            if ( is_woocommerce_activated() && 'true' == $settings['homepage_enable_featured_products'] ) {
                get_template_part( 'includes/featured-products' );
            }

            if ( 'true' == $settings['homepage_enable_features'] ) {
                $args = array( 'title' => $settings['homepage_features_area_title'], 'size' => 235, 'per_row' => 3, 'limit' => $settings['homepage_number_of_features'] );
                $args['before'] = '<section id="features" class="home-section widget_woothemes_features">';
                $args['after'] = '</section>';
                $args['before_title'] = '<header class="block"><h1>';
                $args['after_title'] = '</h1></header>';

                do_action( 'woothemes_features', $args );
            }       

            // Featured Slider.
            woo_featured_slider_loader();

            if ( 'true' == $settings['homepage_enable_testimonials'] ) {
                $args = array( 'title' => $settings['homepage_testimonials_area_title'], 'size' => 80, 'per_row' => 3, 'limit' => $settings['homepage_number_of_testimonials'] );
                $args['before'] = '<section id="testimonials" class="home-section widget_woothemes_testimonials">';
                $args['after'] = '</section>';
                $args['before_title'] = '<header class="block"><h1>';
                $args['after_title'] = '</h1></header>';

                do_action( 'woothemes_testimonials', $args );
            }

            if ( 'true' == $settings['homepage_enable_blog_posts'] ) {
                get_template_part( 'includes/blog-posts' );
            }

            if ( 'true' == $settings['homepage_enable_promotion'] ) {
                get_template_part( 'includes/promotion' );
            }

        ?>
        <?php } ?>    
        </section><!-- /#main -->

        <?php woo_main_after(); ?>

    </div><!-- /#content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Thanks

Erin

Answer (score 0):

With so little code we can't give you a proper answer only guesses.

If the whole website is wrapper in a container and you want only 1 section to be full width then you might consider, changing the html structure of that page, a.k.a

insted of:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

    </div>
    <div class="row">

    </div>
</div>
```

should become:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
</div>
```

(I'm taking in consideration that there might be other elements between the container and that section and you can't close the container with all the sections without tweaking the css for all the section that you need to reopen once again)
If the container is postioned in the header.php, you can close it in the header (only for this template/page) and make a new one in the page/template and use the structure above.

There are JS solutions too, but why complicate things, when it can be simple.

Comment: Thanks drip. I tried in vane. See I added the PHP file that needs to be edited so that 'homepage_enable_intro_message' => 'true' falls under its own CSS block. At the moment everything falls under <section id="main" class="col-full fullwidth">. So I added my own section, but couldn't get the PHP part right and went back to the original PHP file as above.